# JUnit tests accessing the wrong database despite loading the correct application context

Tags: junit, jooq, applicationcontext

I currently have no explanation for what I am seeing here - please let me know if you require further information

I am having an application context file

```
src/test/resources/applicationContext-jooq-test.xml
```

which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- This is needed for the @Transactional annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mz.server" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mz_testdb?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure Spring's transaction manager to use a DataSource -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure jOOQ's TransactionProvider as a proxy to Spring's transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionProvider"
        class="com.mz.server.SpringTransactionProvider">
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure jOOQ's ConnectionProvider to use Spring's TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy,
         which can dynamically discover the transaction context -->
    <bean id="transactionAwareDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
        <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the DSL object, optionally overriding jOOQ Exceptions with Spring Exceptions -->
    <bean id="dslContext" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
        <constructor-arg ref="config" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Invoking an internal, package-private constructor for the example
         Implement your own Configuration for more reliable behaviour -->
    <bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
        <property name="SQLDialect"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">MYSQL</value></property>
        <property name="connectionProvider" ref="connectionProvider" />
        <property name="transactionProvider" ref="transactionProvider" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

As you can see I am *clearly* defining `mz_testdb` as my target database.

For my JUnit tests I have a `AbstractRepositoryTest` which does nothing except initializing the database and bring it into a useful state before tests are starting:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/applicationContext-jooq-test.xml")
public abstract class AbstractRepositoryTest {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AbstractRepositoryTest.class.getName());

    private static DSLContext ctx;

    public AbstractRepositoryTest() {

    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpDatabase() {

        LOGGER.debug("Setting up database for unit tests ..");

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext-jooq-test.xml");
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) applicationContext.getBean("dataSource");

        FlywayDbMain flywayDbMain = new FlywayDbMain();

        boolean databaseOkay = flywayDbMain.setUpCleanDatabase(dataSource);

        AbstractRepositoryTest.ctx = (DSLContext) applicationContext.getBean("dslContext");

        org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(databaseOkay);

    }

    protected static DSLContext getContext() {
        return AbstractRepositoryTest.ctx;
    }
}
```

And of course I am having a test prepared:

```java
public class ShopRepositoryTest extends AbstractRepositoryTest {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ShopRepositoryTest.class.getName());

    private ShopRepository shopRepository;

    private Long shop1Id;

    private Long shop2Id;

    private final static Long LANG_GERMAN = 1L;

    private final static Long LANG_ENGLISH = 2L;

    @Before
    public void before() {

        try {

            this.shopRepository = new ShopRepository(AbstractRepositoryTest.getContext());

            LOGGER.info("Setting up database ..");

            // Shop 1

            this.shop1Id = this.shopRepository.createShop("Shop 1", 46.061785f, 16.464123f, "Europe/Vienna", LANG_GERMAN);

            this.shopRepository.addSupportedLanguage(this.shop1Id, LANG_GERMAN);
            this.shopRepository.addSupportedLanguage(this.shop1Id, LANG_ENGLISH);

            // Shop 2

            this.shop2Id = this.shopRepository.createShop("Shop 2", 46.061785f, 16.464123f, "Europe/Vienna", LANG_GERMAN);

            this.shopRepository.addSupportedLanguage(this.shop2Id, LANG_GERMAN);
            this.shopRepository.addSupportedLanguage(this.shop2Id, LANG_ENGLISH);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteAllItemDetails() {
        // ...
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        LOGGER.debug("All done.");
    }

}
```

Now, the error I am getting is the following:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mz_db.shop' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
```

I have debugged the ship out of my code but I just don't see it. *Where* and *why* am I all of a sudden talking to my dev database `mz_db`? If I step though the code everywhere I look I see that the url is actually correct:

[image]

In fact, there is talk about `mz_db` but that's all in

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-jooq.xml
```

Of course, if I create `mz_db` I am not getting this exception but all the data gets written into this table which is just not what i want.

I am very curious how I managed to do something like this and it must be something stupid which I am not seeing.

What is happening here?

---

I already tried to

- Clean all projects
- Delete `target/` folder
- restart Eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jOOQ per se doesn't care about your JDBC connection URL. That's just the default database to use when tables are not fully qualified. But jOOQ by default fully qualifies tables with schema names (= database names in MySQL). So, if you generate jOOQ tables from your `mz_db` database and run queries against a `mz_testdb` connection, the generated SQL will still fully qualify the `mz_db.shop` table as it was originally generated.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Disable fully qualifying tables using [`Settings.renderSchema`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderSchema)
2. Configure schema mapping using [`Settings.renderMapping`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderMapping) to rewrite `mz_db` to `mz_testdb`

The latter is also documented here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/runtime-schema-mapping

Comment: Oh! I wouldn't have expected that this comes from jOOQ. I think I'll take the `renderMapping` approach in this case! Thanks for your help Lukas!

Comment: If in doubt, you can always [turn on debug logging](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging) to see the SQL generated by jOOQ...